# Oracle Trigger with follows clause throwing variable out of scope

Tags: oracle, triggers, oracle-apex

I have create a trigger which would follow another trigger.
This trigger will be fired when an issue is inserted in p_it_issues table and the approver 1 (p_it_people.approver='approver level 1' from same dept would receive an email notification to approve the issue at first level).
I am receiving cursor out of scope error in this trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE EDITIONABLE TRIGGER  "P_IT_ISSUES_AIU_Notify_Approver_1" 
AFTER 
insert on P_IT_ISSUES 
for each row 
FOLLOWS P_IT_ISSUES_AIU_EMAIL
declare
v_person_id number;
v_email varchar2(255);
v_dept_name varchar2(50);
begin
select p.person_id ,p.person_email,i.dept_name into v_person_id,v_email,v_Dept_name from p_it_people p,p_it_departments i 
where p.assigned_dept=i.dept_id and i.dept_id=:new.related_dept_id and p.approver='Approver 1'  ;

             APEX_MAIL.SEND( 
                 p_to => p.person_email, 
                 p_from => p.person_email, 
                 p_body =>  
                 'You have been assigned a new issue for first level approval.  ' ||chr(10)|| 
                 'The details are below. ' ||chr(10)|| 
                 chr(10)|| 
                 ' Department:'|| i.dept_name ||chr(10)|| 
                 ' Summary: '||:new.issue_summary ||chr(10)|| 
                 ' Status: '||:new.status ||chr(10)|| 
                 'Priority: '||nvl(:new.priority,'-'), 
                  p_subj => 'New Issue for First Level Approval'); 


end;
```

Also the reason why it has follows clause is, the trigger before this is also after insert on p_it_issues table to notify the issue assignee that issue has been assigned, so to avoid mutation i created this trigger using follows clause.

Comment: I think the p.person_email references in the apex_mail API call need to be v_person_id

Comment: Yes, silly mistake! thanks.Replaced variables in email and it worked.

Comment: Please mark the question as answered